# Is there a web server which can embeded with an ASP.NET MVC3 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, installation

Is there a web server I can embed with an ASP.NET MVC3 application?

The goal is to setup an installer where the user does not need to setup the web application on IIS, etc.  The installer will install a web server configure it to listen to some port and host the files from there.

Comment: Have you looked at IIS Express?

Comment: No I haven't look to see if is redistributable.  Good idea though, thank you.

Comment: Hmm, not sure if will run as a service

Comment: Question on running IIS Express as service: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931374/how-to-run-iis-express-as-a-process-started-via-a-windows-service

Answer (score 4):

IIS Express could be used for that purpose, they mention in the FAQ that the MSI can be redistributed:

[IIS Express FAQ](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/901/iis-express-faq/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpListener, [Here's an example](http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2008/07/16/simplest-embedded-web-server-ever-with-httplistener.aspx).

Comment: HttpsListener isn't going to serve a ASP.NET MVC site.  Maybe it could be figured out, but i'm not writing all of that code.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned - use IIS Express OR what you can do is install the version of IIS that would normally be on the system. Check out using WiX for installs and items such as this:

http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Using-pkgmgr-to-install-IIS-7-td5990722.html

You may be able to find someone on the WiX mailing list that has done just this already.

Note - WiX was written by some Microsoft folks and was actually going to be the installer in VS 2010 but was changed unfortunately.