# Manual deployment of MVC4 website on IIS express

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-8

System details : Windows 7, MS Visual Staudion Ultimate 2012, IISExpress 8

Trying to deploy externally (without visual studio)created .NET app on IIS express. 
Steps :

1. I have followed instructions  [how-to-develop-a-simple-asp-net-mvc-project-without-visual-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783378/how-to-develop-a-simple-asp-net-mvc-project-without-visual-studio) for creating application  and
2. copied application folder at location C:\Users\user1\Documents\IISExpress\Logs
3. I am using following definition in c:\\IISExpress\config\applicationhost.config file
   [image]

I searched over internet and found inetmgr related instruction on deploying an app. But inetmgr was not found in my system.
Questions as follows :

- Is step 2 action correct?
- Is xml code correct?
- IISExpress 8 was installed along with VS 2012 ultmate. Still not able to find inetmgr? is this problematic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is step 2 action correct?

No, you claim to have copied the log folder. You'll need the folder containing the web application.

> Is xml code correct?

It looks fine, are you having issues with it?

> IISExpress 8 was installed along with VS 2012 ultmate. Still not able to find inetmgr? is this problematic?

It is problematic that you're trying to host a site manually in IIS Express, as it is [meant as a development server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557369/using-iis-express-to-host-a-low-volume-web-site). Why not just install IIS?

Comment: I copied whole MyMVCApp1 along with web.config, etc contents to Logs folder.okay. means my deployment procedure is wrong. does inet manager is required for iisexpress 8 version? or is there any separate exe for that

Comment: @shraddha your configuration claims the application is in the `C:\NETPROJECTS\MyMVCApp1` directory, is this the case? What happens currently when you visit the url http://localhost:23318/? The `inetmgr` is the IIS Manager, it doesn't work with IIS Express.

Comment: i had to install iis separately.