# Start IIS Express without debugger

Tags: visual-studio-2012, iis-express

For performance reasons I'd like to start the IIS Express Webserver without debugging. Settings the 'compilation debug="false"' parameter in the web.config solves the issue but every time I start debugging my application, Visual Studio displays an error, saying that the debugger could not be attached. If I disable the Web Project's "Always start in debug" I won't get this error but, of course, IIS Express won't start.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635803/how-do-i-start-iis-express

Comment: I do not want to add start scripts for all my web projects. I'm looking for a solution not to auto-attach the debugger to all web projects.

Comment: If you hit Ctrl-F5 to start the project without debugging, IIS Express starts as well, no?

Comment: Yes, that's the behavior I'd like to achieve. But running my GUI in debug mode without being forced to debug the WCF service, too.

Comment: Ah. So you have a website and a service? Are they in separate projects? If they are, set up separate sites in IIS with separate App Pools? Also, you can always start without debugging and then manually attach to the iisexpress.exe process

Comment: I have several services and a WPF application. And I'd like to start the WPF application in debug mode and automatic start all the services in IIS Express but without debugging. Is this possible?