# IIS Express builds successfully but the web page template doesn't open in Visual Studio 2019 (Blazor Project). Any idea on what i should do?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis-express

So im new to Blazor and programming. I created a Blazor WebAssembly project and ran the IIS Express. It took a few seconds to build and the build was successful. But it did not open the browser web page on my localhost showing the template web page.

Can i please get help on this?

Here is an image of the build output

[image]

Here is an image of the build output

[image]

Comment: Did you just Build or did you press F5 (Start Debugging)?

Comment: Also check your debug settings Project > Project Properties > Debug > Launch Browser

Comment: Check if IIS Express is running https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635803/how-do-i-start-iis-express

Comment: i think it was the version of my Visual studio software. i uninstalled it and reinstalled the newer version. it works fine now.

Comment: thank you for the help @Jasen